# pandas agg: get rid of the second level

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the data:

```
   test_num  value
0         1      1
1         1      2
2         1      3
3         2      4
4         2      5
5         2      6
6         3      7
7         3      8
8         3      9
```

I need to return the min and max values in the group:

```
df.groupby('test_num').agg({'value': [('mindata', 'min'), 
    ('maxdata', 'max')]}).reset_index()

  test_num   value        
           mindata maxdata
0        1       1       3
1        2       4       6
2        3       7       9
```

But I need this to have one level:

```
  test_num mindata maxdata
0        1       1       3
1        2       4       6
2        3       7       9
```

How to do it with a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use named aggregations for prevent `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df = df.groupby('test_num').agg(mindata = ('value', 'min'), 
                                maxdata = ('value', 'max')).reset_index()
print (df)
   test_num  mindata  maxdata
0         1        1        3
1         2        4        6
2         3        7        9
```

In your solution is possible use [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) before `reset_index`:

```
(df.groupby('test_num').agg({'value': [('mindata', 'min'), 
                                     ('maxdata', 'max')]})
   .droplevel(0, axis=1)
   .reset_index())
```

Comment: Instead of `_.reset_index()` may be we can add `df.groupby(..., as_index=False)`? Which one would be faster?

Comment: @Ch3steR - Honestly never test it, so no idea.

Comment: On df of size `(9k, 2)` with `reset_index`-> `4.32 ms ± 137 µs per loop`....with `as_index=False` -> `4.22 ms ± 53.6 µs per loop`

Comment: Not that big of a difference though.